will a link click be tracked for INP
I implemented the following two links which do (almost) the same.
They replace the current page content with the content of the about page.
However one will use a default browser navigation and the other one will use an ajax fetch call with javascript.
<a href="/about-us">Click Me!</a>

vs
<a href="/about-us" onclick="fetchAndDisplay(event)">Click Me!</a>

<script>
function fetchAndDisplay(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const url = e.target.href;
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(html => {
        document.body.innerHTML = html;
    });
</script>

My question is - will both links be counted for the Google Core WebVital Metric INP (Interaction to next Paint)?

https://web.dev/articles/inp I think the AJAX fetch would be counted but, a navigation would not be counted.

"we'd measure this from link click until the page is unloaded, however often that has no final paint [...] simple link clicks are ignored for INP in those cases at present"
https://groups.google.com/g/web-vitals-feedback/c/43_7i8vf8Rk
